# 2D diffusion model - forward process

Tags: pytorch, gaussian, noise, variance

Im trying to build  the forward process :
my  data is  2000 2D points uniformly distributed , inside a square, ranging from x = −1, y = −1 to x = 1, y = 1.
and my Scheduler: σ(t) = e5(t−1)., T: 1000 (therefore dt = 1./T = 1e − 3)
As I understand at every timestamp I need to to add Gaussian noise to the image in the previous time stamp, Im very new to this so I searched for some models :
https://www.kaggle.com/code/aakashnain/ddpms-part-2/notebook . unfortunately I dont quite understand how to modify the kaggle code  to fit my purpose , especially this part :

```
# 3. Define number of timesteps
timesteps = 100

# 4. Generate beta (variance schedule)
beta_start = 0.0001
beta_end = 0.05
beta = np.linspace(beta_start, beta_end, num=timesteps, dtype=np.float32)
```

since I already have the beta based on the time "t". σ(t) = e5(t−1) and xt = x0 + σ(t) · ϵ,  ϵ ∼ N (0, I). how can I generate my betas ?
would be happy for your help, and sorry in advance if the question is too "newbie".

I also tried my own code :

```
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
output_points = points.clone()
# Set hyperparameters
T = 1000
dt = 1.0 / T 
noise_scheduler = lambda t:torch.exp(torch.tensor(5.0) * (t - 1))

# Generate uniformly sampled points
num_points = 2000
points = torch.rand(num_points, 2) * 2 - 1  # Uniformly sample points in the square [-1, 1] x [-1, 1]

# Perform the forward process on the points
for t in range(T):
    epsilon = torch.randn(num_points, 2)  # Sample Gaussian noise
    sigma = noise_scheduler(t*dt)  # Compute noise schedule for the current time step
     output_points += sigma * epsilon  # Add noise to the points

# Plot the original points and the points after the forward process
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], color='blue', label='Original Points')
plt.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], color='red', alpha=0.5, label='Points after Forward Process')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.title('Forward Process')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

But it seems that it is not giving the desired result :

[image]

Alternatively would be happy to get your feedback on the problem in my code :)